# HTTPS Proxy for existing HTTP application

Tags: http, proxy, https

I have a running HTTP web application and I am facing problems to make it run over HTTPS.

I am thinking of bringing some HTTPS Proxy that accepts user requests and forward it to the HTTP web app.

What do you think of that? and How can I accomplish that?

Comment: It is difficult to offer advice without any hint of what the problems are.

Comment: Well, Here's the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021471/securing-j2ee-1-4-webservice-in-jdeveloper

Answer (score 3):

Setting up [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) is a no-brainer - and its available for Unix/Linux/Posix/MSWindows (you might have mentioned what OS you are using).

(Also you can run the program to encrypt or decrpyt, at the server or at the client side)

Comment: Someone voted this up today - so it came across my radar - the answer is a bit dated and there are other solutions now available. Stud does a similar job to Stunnel but runs as a single-threaded event based server (making it more scalable). Apache Traffic Server can add SSL termination and also caching and cluster capability (again event based) but more suitable for complex instlallations. Nginx can (again event based) can run as a reverse proxy and add SSL.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run Apache Httpd (for example) using HTTPS and use `mod_proxy_http` as a reverse proxy to forward the requests to your existing HTTP server. Of course, for this to be of any use, you'd need the reverse proxy and the target server to be connected in such a way that connections cannot be sniffed or altered.

You may find that the existing server needs certain extra settings for it to be aware it's using HTTPS (for example, [special Valves in Apache Tomcat](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://blog.xebia.fr/2009/09/23/securiser-tomcat-5-derriere-un-proxy-apache-2-https/&ei=YnPJTPfREYf64Aa89sWTAQ&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBgQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3DS%25C3%25A9curiser%2BTomcat%2B5%2Bderri%25C3%25A8re%2Bun%2Bproxy%2BApache%2B2%2BHTTPS%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DG) to set the HTTPS flag to true).

Answer (score 0):

Apache httpd [reverse-proxy](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)?